# Empty passphrase created ssh key-pair refusing empty passphrase when authenticating

Tags: linux, ssh, ubuntu-14.04, lxc

After @Sarke help I reach that solution:

Here the fixed version, the original broken version cant help nobody.

About why I need to be able to SSH from one container to the other it that i need High-availability to some clients and want to do Disk mirroring with DRBD or rsync and want to to it over a ssh tunel.

xfce4-terminal -T LocalTerm
exit

At LocalTerm:

```
lxc stop C1  
lxc stop C2  

lxc delete C1  
lxc delete C2  

lxc launch ubuntu:14.04 C1  
lxc launch ubuntu:14.04 C2  

lxc list --format csv  

xfce4-terminal -T C1Term -e "bash -c 'lxc exec C1 -- /bin/bash; exec bash; exit 0;'"  
xfce4-terminal -T C2Term -e "bash -c 'lxc exec C2 -- /bin/bash; exec bash; exit 0;'"
```

At C1Term and C2Term:

```
apt-get update  
apt-get upgrade  
apt-get install netcat net-tools  
apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client  
cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.original  
    nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config   
        --------  
        Port 2222  
        PubkeyAuthentication yes  
        --------
```

At LocalTerm:

```
lxc restart C1  
lxc restart C2
```

At C2Term:

```
lxc exec C2 -- /bin/bash; exec bash
```

At C1Term:

```
lxc exec C1 -- /bin/bash; exec bash  
ssh-keygen -t rsa  
    --------  
    Here using no password and all default options  
    --------
```

At LocalTerm:

```
rm -rf /home/myUser/localFolder/*  

lxc file pull --recursive C1/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /home/myUser/localFolder/  
cat /home/myUser/localFolder/id_rsa.pub >> /home/myUser/localFolder/authorized_keys_tail  
lxc file push --recursive /home/myUser/localFolder/authorized_keys_tail C2/root/.ssh/  
lxc exec C2 -- sh -c "sudo cat /root/.ssh/authorized_keys_tail >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

At C1Term:

```
sudo ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pem root@10.20.30.40 -p2222
```

Comment: `ssh-keygen -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -e -m pem > /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pem` Try this with the private key file (id_rsa) instead of the public key file (id_rsa.pub).

Comment: @Kenster , Thanks for the help but the error message remains the same after pointing to private key as I detailed above on Test02.

Comment: What does `sudo ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pem root@C2-machine-ip -p2222 -vvv` give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ssh-copy-id` is used to append the user's public key to the remote's `authorized_keys` file.  This is the file used to validate the connection.  Copying the public key file over does nothing.

To me this doesn't seem like a LXC/LXD issue, but a SSH usage issue.

In order to use `ssh-copy-id` we need to validate somehow, and most likely our public key is not there yet so it would require a password.  If a password is not set or available this needs to be done manually.

Try

```
lxc file pull --recursive C1/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /home/myUser/localFolder/
cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys
lxc file push --recursive /home/myUser/localFolder/authorized_keys C2/root/.ssh/
```

But why do you need to be able to SSH from one container to the other?

Comment: Your solution solved the problem, the full solution on question body, thanks. About why is that i need High-availability to some clients and want to do Disk mirroring with DRBD or RSync and want to to it over a ssh tunel.